# (In Scala,) Is there anything that can be done with generic type parameters of classes but not with abstract type members?

Tags: scala, generics, types, parameters, abstract

It is clear that one cannot parametrize a method with abstract type members. However, is there any reason for the existence of generic type parameters *for classes* except for the convenience issue that types and instantiations can be written shorter, e.g. in the following abstracted List-ArrayList scenario:

Here, the parametrization is realized by an abstract type member:

```
trait base1 {
    type X
    def id(x: X): X
}
class extension1 extends base1 {
    override def id(x: X): X = x
}
val ext1: base1 { type X = Int } = new extension1 { type X = Int }
val y1 = ext1.id(0)
```

Here it is realized by a generic type parameter:

```
trait base2[X] {
    def id(x: X): X
}
class extension2[X] extends base2[X] {
    override def id(x: X): X = x
}
val ext2: base2[Int] = new extension2[Int]
val y2 = ext2.id(0)
```

The latter solution is more convenient and readable. This is important by itself but I am interested in the more general, i.e. *semantic*, perspective.

[This](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/scalas%5Ftype%5Fsystem.html) interview with Martin Odersky is a great introduction but it does not seem to answer this question.

Thank you very much for any hint or explanation!

Comment: I am sorry. But I dont understand the exact question. What is it you are specifically asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book *Programming Scala* by Dean Wampler and Alex Payne gives a good [overview](http://books.google.de/books?id=mincYfsQleMC&pg=PA270#v=onepage&q&f=false) about when to use type parameters vs. abstract type members.

In addition to not beeing able to parameterize methods (which can be a big restriction) there are two restrictions of abstract type members:

1. **Abstract types can not be variance annotated** (See [p. 269](http://books.google.de/books?id=mincYfsQleMC&pg=PA269#v=onepage&q&f=false)) Meaning there is no equivalent to `trait List[+T]` or `trait Function[-T,+R]` with abstract type members.
2. Abstract types can lead to unjustified type errors with path-dependent types. There is an example for this on [p. 272](http://books.google.de/books?id=mincYfsQleMC&pg=PA272#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Would that imply the following: if abstract type parameters had variance annotation (which could probably be specified along the same lines as the one of generic type parameters) – and unjustified type errors (I have not really understood the example on p.272 since the following page is blanked out) would be rules out by improved compiler design – there would not be any reason for generic type parameters? (for classes, for methods they are relevant, of course)

Comment: @Majakovskij Consider Java interoperability as well.

Comment: @Majakovskij Type parameters and type members are partly redundant. Type parameters are a less verbose and still sufficient for most real world scenarios. If you need named types then abstract type members come into play. The fact that the Scala standard library does very rarely use them itself reflects the fact that it is kind of awkward to instantiate them. I actually think the [DOT-Calculus](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~boyland/fool2012/papers/fool2012_submission_3.pdf) and [DOTTY](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty) aim at unifying them which would result in something like named type parameters!?